# Knockoutjs throws exception when trying to create series of unordered lists

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm attempting to create a series of `<ul>` tags using the `foreach:` context.  The goal is to iterate through the list, and start a *new* `<ul>` for every 4th item.  My code so far is:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Areas">
   <li><span>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: AreaId, checked: $root.AreasImpacted" />
      <label><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></label>
   </span></li>

   <!-- ko if: ($index() % 4 == 0) -->
   </ul><ul>
   <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

When I do this, I get the exception:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot find closing comment tag to
>   match:  ko if: ($index() % 4 == 0)

It seems to not like the `</li><li>` content within the `if` comment block, probably because the DOM parser is scratching its head on how to actually *parse* this.  If I change it to:

```
<!-- ko if: ($index() % 4 == 0) -->
<li>Fake!</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then it'll work perfectly (that is, create a fake `<li>` every 4th element.

I'm open to other ideas of accomplishing this as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the initial DOM (before Knockout activates) is illegal, and Knockout doesn't work by pasting HTML into the DOM, it actually copies it into a javascript DOM object, which it inserts into the DOM. `</ul><ul>` isn't a legal object, so Knockout won't be able to turn it into a template. Even if it could, the `foreach` binding is on the original `<ul>`, not the new one started by the `if`, so the Knockout code that added items would still be operating on the first list.

So, in summation, Knockout's `foreach` and `template` bindings don't work by building HTML as if it's a string.

You will need a more complex solution.

[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nk4RE/) would work, but I don't know if this is still what you are going for:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: chunkedList, as: 'areas' } -->
<span>SPLIT!</span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: areas">
    <li><span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->

var Viewmodel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.chunkedList = ko.computed(function() {
        var result = [];
        var chunk = [];
        self.items().forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (index % 4 === 0) {
                chunk = [];
                result.push(chunk);
            };
            chunk.push(item);
        });
        return result;
    });
};
```

Comment: Excellent!  This should work, though I think I might go the route of changing my CSS around so I don't *have* to break up the list into chunks of 4..

Comment: That's probably a better way to go.